# NavigationBar not showing on TableviewController in swift

Tags: swift

I have a CollectionView running in my project and the collectionViewController connected to another tableview using custom segue as follows.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedMenuItem = indexPath.row

    //Present new view controller
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)

    var destViewController : UINavigationController


    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewTableView") as UINavigationController
        break
    default:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewTableView") as UINavigationController
        break
    }
    self.presentViewController(destViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

above code populating my NewTableview successfully but the tableview missing navigation bar completely.

so far  my tries as follow...

- i embedded new navigationController to collectionView results remain unchanged.
- i embedded new navigationController to NewTableView results remain unchanged.
- i tried unwind segue method using custom navigation button action method.so i insert the navigation bar item and button to the view and Method works,but it works strangly when navigation bar button pressed it  takes me to my main collection view controller thats what i what.but i have another back button appears in collection view rowindex item name on it.when i pressed the button it take me back to the NewTableView its like looping through.

i don't know what i am missing (any delegate method).and i noticed the newTableView data loading from the bottom with animation...

i wondering is there any way to put a navigation programmatically with back button behaviour...

Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to instantiate the navigation controller, not the actual view controller from your storyboard. So instead of instantiating `NewTableView` (the view controller you want embedded in the navigation controller), you should add an identifier to your `UINavigationController` so that it will be instantiated instead of the view controller itself.

Just imagine that you reuse the `NewTableView` controller which does not require a navigation controller as its root, how would iOS be aware of that ? So add an identifier to your hosting `UINavigationController` and instantiate that. The navigation controller has a root dependency on the `rootViewController` which will be shown by default, so you only need to display the `UINavigationController` and the `NewTableView` controller will be shown based on the dependency it has with the navigation controller.